# Inheritance with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js

I have some code like this:

```
var A = function(a,b,c) {
  var self = this;
  self.a = ko.observable(a);
  ... 


  self.function1 = ko.computed(function () {
      dothing(a);
      ...
  } 

  self.function2 = ko.computed(function () {
      dothing(b);
      ...
  }
}

var B = function(a,b,c,d) {
    var self = this;
  self.a = ko.observable(a);
  ... 


  self.function1 = ko.computed(function () {
      dothing(a);
      ...
  } 

  self.function2 = ko.computed(function () {
      dothing(b);
      ...
  }
}
```

How can I "extract" function1 and function2 to a function that A and B can share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just where prototypes fit in:

```
function AB()
{};//empty object
AB.prototype.function1 = function()
{
    var self = this;//doesn't have access to self, but `this` will point to either A or B
    //do stuff
};
var A = function()
{
    var self = this;//constructor
}
var B = function()
{
    var self = this;//constructor
}
A.prototype = new AB;
A.prototype.constructor = A;
B.prototype = new AB;
B.prototype.constructor = B;
//marginally shorter:
A.prototype = B.prototype = new AB;
A.prototype.constructor = A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;
//instances:
var foo = new A();
var bar = new B();
console.log(foo.function1 === bar.function1);//logs true
```

Having said that, personally, I prefer to define my constructors *regularly*:

```
function A()
{
    var self = this;
}
foo = new A();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).constructor.name);//logs A
```

Whereas your code assigns an anonymous function to a variable, which means that the constructor doesn't have a name:

```
foo = new A();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).constructor.name);//logs ''
```

It's not *that* big of a deal, but just so you know...

---

Reference a method from the global (or any other) scope:

```
var virtualNewFunction = new A();//create object
virtualNewFunction = virtualNewFunction.function1;//virtualNewFunction now references function1
virtualNewFunction();
```

The closure will be accessible (exposed), still, but be *very* careful with `this`:

```
A = function()
{
    var self = this;
    this.function1 = function()
    {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(self);
    };
}
foo = new A();
foo.function1();//logs A twice
foo = foo.function1
foo();//logs this -> window! self => A
```

An other possibility is *"borrowing"* a function:

```
A = function()
{
    var self = this;
    this.function1 = function()
    {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(self);
    };
}
B = function()
{//no method
    var self = this;
}
foo = new A();
bar = new B();
foo.function1.apply(bar,[]);//call as though function1 was method of B
```

Again, be careful: in this case `this` logs `B`, but `self` still references `A`! You could build in certain *"safety nets"*:

```
    this.function1 = function()
    {
        self = this !== window && this !== self ? this : self;//redefine self to current caller object, unless it's window 
        console.log(this);
        console.log(self);
    };
```

But honestly, you might do well [reading up on the this operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to grasp all this referencing trickery. It's not *that* hard once you get the basics. Also check the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods for more details on how to *"share/borrow"* methods

Comment: I edited the question regarding function1/function2, can you please take a look?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean... I'll edit my answer to show some more stuff you can do, though:

Comment: I mean that function1 and function2 use variables that passed to A and B

Comment: In that case [take a look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @Vimvq1987: if you're referring to `var self`, take a look at my last update, when you use `apply` or `call` the closure vars are passed on. If you're referring to the properties of either object then, you can access them using something like `A.function1 = function(){console.log(self.propertyOfA);}`, which will work regardless of the call context. I'm sorry but I don't really get what you need to know, but I'm pretty sure you can do everything you want to and more, but I fear you'll have to spend some time reading the MDN links I provided, and perhaps the ECMA standard (which is pretty dry)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the scope of the function by pulling it out of that object.

```
var function1 = function() {

}

var function2 = function() {

}

var A = function(a,b,c) {
  var self = this;
  self.a = ko.observable(a);
  ... 


  self.function1 = ko.computed(function1)

  self.function2 = ko.computed(function2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the underscore.js extend functionality to do the inheritance.

Comment: This is not very clear.  Side note, lo-dash (http://lodash.com/) is a better version of underscore.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var AB=function(){
    self=this;
    self.function1=function(){
                   //----something------
                  }
    self.function1=function(){
                   //----something------
                  }

   }


     var A=function(){
     var self=this;
     AB.apply(self,arguments);
     } 

    var B=function(){
     var self=this;
     AB.apply(self,arguments);
        }
```