# Function as method in another function

Tags: javascript, function, methods, nested

I'm trying to learn JS from online tutorial - http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#33 , you can test JS code there. I'm trying to understand nesting functions as methods inside of other functions and what "this" keyword is referencing then. Why if I put on above site code from below - it doesn't work? Could someone explain that aspect of JS?

```
function Ninja(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.changeName = function(newname) {
    this.name = newname;
    this.anotherFunction = function(newname2) {
      this.name2 = newname2;
    }
  }
}

var ninja = new Ninja("John");
assert( ninja.name == "John", "The name has been set on initialization" );

// ninja.anotherFunction("Luken");
// ninja.changeName.anotherFunction("Luken");
// Why both above functions doesn't work?

assert(ninja.name2, "It works?");

ninja.changeName("Bob");
assert( ninja.name == "Bob", "The name was successfully changed." );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple:

```
function Ninja(name)
{//this points to Ninja object inside constructor scope
    this.name = name;
    this.changeName = function(newname)
    {//method of Ninja, this points to context object, ie Ninja
        this.name = newname;//accesses the name property of Ninja
        this.anotherFunction = function(newname2)
        {//defines new method for this ==> Ninja object
            this.name2 = newname2;//context object is Ninja
        };
    };
}
var foo = new Ninja('foobar');
foo.name;//foobar
foo.changeName;//function, is defined in constructor
typeof foo.anotherFunction//undefined because it's assigned when the changeName method is called!
foo.changeName('Me');
foo.name;//Me
foo.anotherFunction('You');//works: changeName was called, and assigned anotherFunction to foo (instance of Ninja)
foo.name2;//You
```

What happened: simple, by invoking the changeName method, `anotherFunction` was defined and assigned to `this`. At that time `this` referenced the `Ninja` object, so the method was assigned to the instance of `Ninja` from which the `changeName` method was invoked. Prior to calling the `changeName` method, the `anotherFunction` method simply didn't exist.

Though this might seem useless or stupid, it does make sense. What you need to remember is that functions/methods are, in essence stand-alone objects. In this code, they just happen to be defined as properties/methods, but they needn't be used as such. Going back to the code above:

```
foo.name;//Me
bar = {};//some object
foo.changeName.apply(bar,['You']);
foo.name;//Me, nothing has changed, the changeName method was applied to the bar object
bar.name;//You, in the apply call, this pointed to bar, not foo
typeof bar.anotherFunction;//function
//You could even create the anotherFunction globally:
//  JUST TO SHOW YOU CAN, THIS IS DANGEROUS
//  ONLY USE THIS IF YOU KNOW WHAT THE POSSIBLE CONSEQUESES ARE!
foo.changeName.call();//in global scope
typeof antoherFunction;//function ==> this function is now globally available
```

The `changeName` method can be applied to *any* object, adding a new method, changeing/adding certain properties to that particular instance.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` is determined at the time the function is invoked, not the time when it is defined. So in your code, you have to different values of `this`: When `ninja.changeName()` is called, you don't specify a value for `this`, so it's either undefined or whatever it might be right now.

The `new` operator, on the other hand, does set `this` before it called the function `Ninja`.

What you need to do is "save" the value of `this` inside of `Ninja` so the inner functions continue to use that (instead of whatever random value might be in `this` at the time they are called). Doing this is more simple than it sounds:

```
function Ninja(name){
  this.name = name;

  var self = this; // Create a hidden reference to "this" that is only visible in
                   // any functions defined before we return

  self.changeName = function(newname) {
    self.name = newname;
    self.anotherFunction = function(newname2) {
      self.name2 = newname2;
    }
  }
}
```

This works because JavaScript keeps a copy of the context (= all reachable variables) around when you define a function.

Comment: As an additional point, `changeName` will actually define `anotherFunction` on the `Ninja` instance every time it is called (if called as a method on `Ninja`) - it just needs to be called first.  So `ninja.changeName("Bob"); ninja.anotherFunction("Joe");` would work, but not the other way around.

Comment: Just a side-note, by using `self` or `that` (a closure variable), you could inadvertently expose an instance when borrowing a method [some examples in my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675276/inheritance-with-knockout-js/12675582#12675582)